# JSQMessagesViewController Y GeoFire no son compatibles?

Tags: xcode, firebase, swift3, pods

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en **Xcode** con **Swift 3** para **IOS** donde estoy utilizando GeoFire para saber la localización de los usuarios pero cuando intento installar el pod de **JSQMessagesViewController** en mi proyecto me sale un error con GeoFire:

> "FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseDatabase.h" not found.

Sin agregar nada más al proyecto solo con instalar el pod de JSQMessagesViewController me sale ese error con GeoFire..

¿Por que es esto? ¿Tiene solución? Gracias.

Comment: checa que la clase firebasedatabase.h este implementada en tu proyecto, recuerda que siempre se tienen que ligar las clases, cuando creas una desde xcode te da la opcion de crear la clase desde la clase padre... si tienes fotos del error podriamos darte una solucion mas clara en caso que no fuera por eso, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Basándome en la documentación de **Firebase** tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

1. En tu pod añadir: `pod 'Firebase/Database'`
2. Posteriormente, añade en tu fichero swift el framework de la siguiente forma:

   ```
   import Firebase
   ```
3. Por último debes seguir las instrucciones tal y como indica la documentación de Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/start

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Un saludo.